# Returning loop counter variables within a stored function created inside aforementioned loop in JavaScript - more details in question body

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, variables, scope

I am new to JavaScript and I am going through freeCodeCamp. The current lesson has two examples which I tried to describe in the title but easier to just show below:

Case 1: Using `var` for loop counter:

```
var printNumTwo;
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  if (i === 2) {
    printNumTwo = function() {
      return i;
    };
  }
}
console.log(printNumTwo());
```

Case 2: Using `let` for loop counter variable:

```
let printNumTwo;
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  if (i === 2) {
    printNumTwo = function() {
      return i;
    };
  }
}
console.log(printNumTwo());
console.log(i);
```

In Case 1, since `i` is declared using `var`, and it is not enclosed in a function body or static initialization block, it has global scope. Thus when you call `console.log(printNumTwo());` it will print 3 (the most up to date value of the global variable `i`).

I am confused about Case 2. According to the lesson, the line `console.log(i);` Will display an error saying that `i` is not defined. This makes sense to me as `i` was defined with `let` in the for-loop, so it is block scoped to that for-loop. Since we are now outside the for-loop the line `console.log(i);` does not have visibility on `i`.

However, apparently the line `console.log(printNumTwo());` will display the value 2. Should it not also display a message saying that `i` is not defined? In this case we are calling `printNumTwo()` from outside of the for-loop (after the for-loop has finished running), and thus we are once again referencing `i` from outside of the for-loop, and so my understanding is that it should not have visibility on `i`.

Again I am new to JavaScript, perhaps there is some knowledge I am missing or misunderstanding. I didn't quite know how to phrase this in a way that I can search it on Google so I was hoping to get an explanation here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer is basically: because `printNumTwo` references a function that references the `i` with value `2`, that `i` is kept alive and not discarded after the loop.

Comment: Every function in JavaScript maintains a reference to its outer lexical environment... [How do javascript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: "*we are once again referencing `i` from outside of the for-loop*" - no, you're referencing and calling the function from outside the loop. The function (the code that references `i`) was defined inside the loop, and only that matters for variable visibility.

Comment: @ĐinhCarabus thank you, I believe that explanation of closures is what I was looking for